# Why is the http prefix being stripped out of my links?

Tags: 7, navigation, wysiwyg

I'm having the weirdest issue site-wide on a Drupal 7.23 website, when I create a link via the Link module or via the WYSIWYG like the following `<a href="http://www.example.com">Link text</a>` and view the source on the page or node, it is rendered without the http prefix (`<a href="www.example.com">Link text</a>`).

I've never seen this before, any ideas? I switched themes and turned off all modules, but it still does it.

I printed the render array function and it always prints with http://.

I have Google pagespeed on my server to compress the HTML and jQuery, has anyone heard of links having the 'http://' stripped from the `href=` before?

Comment: What's the input used on the field(s) in question? Plain text? full html? something unique?